# Facing issue: scan dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I've created apis in nodejs to scan and query dynamoDB table(contains 70K records).
I'm stuck with scan api. I've two APIs for scan - 
1. Scanning table with limit of 500 - getting proper response
2. Scanning table without any limit -  response code 403

And if I'm calling the same query without any limit through cli, getting full response.

Not getting what's the problem.

```
api.get('/deviceData', function (request) { // GET all users
  return dynamoDb.scan({ 
        TableName: 'student', 
        Limit: 500
    }).promise()
      .then(response => response.Items);
});

api.get('/deviceData-scan', function (request) { // GET all users
  return dynamoDb.scan({ 
        TableName: 'student'
    }).promise()
      .then(response => response.Items);
});
```

Comment: Can you please show us an example of how are you using those APIS?

Comment: Please have a look at the dynamodb scan limits : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Comment: api.get('/deviceData', function (request) { // GET all users
  return dynamoDb.scan({ 
  TableName: 'student', 
  Limit: 500
 }).promise()
      .then(response => response.Items);
});

api.get('/deviceData-scan', function (request) { // GET all users
  return dynamoDb.scan({ 
  TableName: 'student'
 }).promise()
      .then(response => response.Items);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check how to use `scan` `multiple time` its help you.

```
function getData() {
    let params = {
      TableName: 'student'
    };
    let finalResult = [];
      let queryExecute = function () {
        documentClient.scan(params, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('failure', err);
          } else {
            finalResult = finalResult.concat(result.Items);
            // check if more data exists.
            if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
              params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
              queryExecute();
            } else {
              console.log('all data', finalResult);
            }
          }
        });
      };
      queryExecute();
  },
```