# AWS DynamoDB Lambda Scan with key

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am currently making a lambda scan where I need to scan a table which currently is bigger than 1mb (the size limit of a single scan). However, my current experience doesnt allow me to rewrite the code for repetitive actions. 
This is the current call:

```
 const params = {
  TableName: 'product',
};
let items = []
try {
  const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
  items = result.Items;
  if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
    const newResult = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
    items.concat(newResult.Items)
  }
  callback(null, success(items));
} catch (e) {
  callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
}
```

So it fires two times, but it should keep on going until the last key is undefined. Any help would be much appreciated!

Greetings Bram

Comment: Please check may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554652/facing-issue-scan-dynamo-db/52569285#52569285

Comment: this is it! Cheers, Tiisetso answer is also correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a  [recursive function](https://techterms.com/definition/recursivefunction) that will stop when the `LastEvaluatedKey` is undefined. It will keep on collecting the results of the scan until the LastEvaluatedKey is undefined and then it will return you the results of the scan.

```
async function scanTillEnd(params, items){
     const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
     items.concat(result.Items)
     //check if they are more items to get
     if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
       params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
       //scan the table again
       return await scanTillEnd(params, items)
    }
    else
       //have scanned till the end, return the results
       return items
}
const params = {
    TableName: 'product',
};
let items = []
let results = scanTillEnd(params,items)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!